# Script to receive file from downloadpage and upload/save on server

Tags: php, asp.net

I would like to know the possiblities for automating a current manual procedure.

I have a script that reads csv-files into a mysql database. The csv-file is fetched by visiting different sites, mostly asp och php pages that automatically starts a doqnload of the csv to the local Download-folder. Then I upload it to my server where the csv->db script handles it.

Is there a way to fetch and place the csv on the server with e.g. a php script that I can set to run automatically with a cron job?

Hope this question is OK for this forum. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put all the urls in a text file and download them using wget in Linux; for example:

```
wget --input-file=file_with_urls_listed_one_per_line.txt
```

You can also get [wget](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm) for Windows in case your server is not a Linux box.

Comment: thank you, the site is on a hosted server so I hope I have access to do  it. Do you know if I can set this running after a schedule aswell?

Comment: Yes, you can either do it in a cron job in Linux or through tha task scheduler in windows.